# Using re.findall in a txt file

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7

I want to use `re.findall` for detecting how many times is a a word displayed in a .txt file. Also I need that if I'm trying to count how many times the word *Hello* appears in the text ***Hello**oo* to be detected.

Here is all the code I have:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import re

total = 0

with open('text.txt') as f:
    for line in f:
        total = re.findall('Hello')

print total
```

Comment: It looks like your forgot to ask a question in your question. Please red [ask] and provide a [MCVE].

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why even use regex?

The `count()` method would do the same thing:

```
with open('text.txt') as f:

    total = f.read()
    print total.count('Hello')
```

And does not require importing modules, since it is inbuilt.

When using regex also not it is advisable to use `r` as a raw string prefix. `total = re.findall(r'Hello')`

Answer (score 3):

Creating a file:

```
echo "Hellooo there.
Hello hello Hello" > file.txt
```

And finding all occurrences of `"Hello"`:

```
In [1]: import re

In [2]: with open('file.txt') as f:
   ...:     all_hellos = re.findall('Hello', f.read())
   ...:

In [3]: print(len(all_hellos))
3
```

The above will only look for `Hello` but not `hello`. And this will cache the entire file in memory, so this will be fine unless you are using big files.

Remember `re.findall()` will return a list of all occurrences found, not the number of occurrences.

Comment: Why not simply use `str.count` if you don't use `re.finditer` for memory efficiency?

Comment: @timgeb str.count looks nice. I never knew about that. I didn't know if the user was looking to use `re.findall` specifically.